# How Implicit differentiate in order to get a differential equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Starts with this **implicit equation**:

`(x - a)^2 + y^2 == 1`(1) ( circles on x -axis ) $(x-a)^2+y^2=1$

Is the set of equations of the given circles. This set contains one parameter namely `a`. So, it is the solution set of a differential equation of the first order. ( ?) Differentiating both members of (1) yields

`(x - a) + y*Derivative[1][y] =0`  (2)          $(x-a)+y y'=0$

I must try to get a differential equation out of the implicit differentiation of equation(2)
The problem is: how to do that?

-There is a total differential command.

Out of equations (1) and (2) can a be eliminated *a*, with should give this differential equation:

$y^2+y^2 \left(y'\right)^2=1$

Doing by hand equation(1) : $2 (x-a) (x-a)'+2 y y'=0$

Note:
There are 2 methods to get y' out of a implicit equation

- differentiate both members of equation  to x (note: beware of y)
- take from both members the differential ( to be done yet )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first equation is:

```
eqn1 = (x - a)^2 + y^2 == 1;
```

[`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) `y` to create a function `y[x]` and do the derivative w.r.t `x` to get the second equation:

```
eqn2 = D[eqn1 /. y -> y[x], x]
```

[`Eliminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html.en) the parameter `a`

```
Eliminate[{eqn1 /. y -> y[x], eqn2}, a]
```

> [image: res]

Comment: BMF ,thanks.  That is the right differential equation!
Understanding implicit differentation in MMA is not that easy

Comment: @janhardo don't mention. Glad I was able to help. You can `DSolve` the last result just so you know :)

Comment: After spending some time working with the y[x] notation in MMA, I think it is more convenient to just use y as books do.
Makes it more complicated the y[x] notation and more work , agree?